# C# ASP.Net MVC Updating Multiple rows in database is creating extra rows

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have in my database one to two rows that can and will be updated at a given time based on the  `Id`. This is a `List<>` of data that I'm able to send to the View and submit it to the `[HttpPost]` method in the controller just fine but when I call the update method I've created, It finds the corresponding rows and goes thru the `foreach` loop supposedly updating them but really just adds the updated data as two new rows to the table. I cant seem to figure out what Im doing wrong.

**Table before update**

```
+------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|  ID  | ItemID | PriceTypeID | ListTypeID | DirectPrice |
+------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 1021 |  62238 |           2 |          1 |        0.00 |
| 1022 |  62238 |           3 |          1 |        0.00 |
+------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

**Update Function**

```
public static void UpdateItem(List<PricingOptionDTO> pricingOptionDTO)      
using (DBContext context = new DBContext()) {

 foreach (var item in pricingOptionDTO)
 {
     Entities.PricingOption pricingOptionTb = context.PricingOptions.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(item.ID)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (pricingOptionTb != null)
           {                                                
            pricingOptionTb .DirectPrice = item.DirectPrice;                
            pricingOptionTb .Increment = item.BidIncrement;
            pricingOptionTb .WarningCap = item.BidWarningCap;
           }

         context.PricingOptions.Add(pricingOptionTb);
         context.SaveChanges(); 
   }
       
      context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

**Table after update**

```
+------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|  ID  | ItemID | PriceTypeID | ListTypeID | DirectPrice |
+------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
| 1021 |  62238 |           2 |          1 |        0.00 |
| 1022 |  62238 |           3 |          1 |        0.00 |
| 1023 |  62238 |           2 |          1 |        1.00 |
| 1024 |  62238 |           3 |          1 |        2.00 |
+------+--------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: i thought entity framework has an AddOrUpdate method for this case... why dont you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is missing from your example:

```
context.PricingOptions.Add(PricingOption);
```

What is "PricingOption" here?

The most obvious looking thing missing from the example that might explain the behaviour you are seeing is the need for an `else` condition:

```
 Entities.PricingOption pricingOptionTb = context.PricingOptions.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(item.ID)).SingleOrDefault();

if (pricingOptionTb != null)
{                                                
    pricingOptionTb .DirectPrice = item.DirectPrice;                
    pricingOptionTb .Increment = item.BidIncrement;
    pricingOptionTb .WarningCap = item.BidWarningCap;
}
else 
    context.PricingOptions.Add(PricingOption);
```

However it's not clear what "PricingOption" is here given you were iterating over a set of DTO. Where this issue commonly appears is when using Automapper to construct an entity from a DTO thinking that because it has an existing ID, adding it to the DbContext will be interpreted as an update. Unfortunately EF only tracks updates against tracked entity references so if you give it a different reference to the same data it will treat it as an insert.

On a side note: When loading an entity where you expect 0 or 1 entity to come back, use `SingleOrDefault` rather than `FirstOrDefault`. This provides an assertion that only 1 record should be found (or not). When using the `First*` methods you should always be expecting and allowing for the possibility of multiple matches, and that being the case always include an `OrderBy*` clause to ensure your execution and selection are predictable.

Update: To handle update or insert scenarios you would want something like:

```
 Entities.PricingOption pricingOptionTb = context.PricingOptions.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(item.ID)).SingleOrDefault();

if (pricingOptionTb != null)
{                                                
    pricingOptionTb .DirectPrice = item.DirectPrice;                
    pricingOptionTb .Increment = item.BidIncrement;
    pricingOptionTb .WarningCap = item.BidWarningCap;
}
else 
{
    pricingOptionTb = new PricingOption
    {
        DirectPrice = item.DirectPrice,
        Increment = item.BidIncrement,
        WarningCap = item.BidWarningCap
    }
    context.PricingOptions.Add(pricingOptionTb);
}
```

Ideally though you should either separate Add vs Update calls explicitly as separate methods and guard against Add requests where a row already exists, or Updates where a row doesn't exist, or consider inspecting the passed in ID or a state value on the DTO. I.e. If ID = 0 it is a new record, otherwise treat it as an existing item that should exist in the DB.

```
if (item.ID == 0) // New item.
{
    // Consider adding a validation check for duplicate pricing options.
   var duplicatePricingOption == context.PricingOptions
       .Any(x => x.DirectPrice == item.DirectPrice
           && x.Increment == item.Increment
           && x.WarningCap == item.WarningCap);
   if (duplicatePricingOption)
       throw new ArgumentException("An existing pricing option exists for this combination.");

   var pricingOption = new PricingOption
   {
       DirectPrice = item.DirectPrice,
       Increment = item.BidIncrement,
       WarningCap = item.BidWarningCap
   };
   context.PricingOptions.Add(pricingOption);
}
else
{
    var pricingOption = context.PricingOptions.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(item.ID)).Single();

    pricingOption.DirectPrice = item.DirectPrice;                
    pricingOption.Increment = item.BidIncrement;
    pricingOption.WarningCap = item.BidWarningCap;
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I updated the code so that it reflects the correct context. `pricingOptionTb` instead of `PricingOption`.

Comment: That code wouldn't work if no existing row is found because pricingOptionTb would be Null in that case. Did you add the missing `else` condition around the `Add`?

Comment: All valid points and a lot of information that I didn't think about and or aware of. I think I was using the `Add()` incorrectly thinking it was adding the data to the object when I should have been using something else. I am looking to just update the given fields.

Comment: so I really don't even need to `Add()` anything? just assign it to the `pricingOption ` object?

Comment: Yes, if you are updating an existing object and EF is set up the default way (with change tracking enabled) you just fetch it, update the values and call `SaveChanges` .`Add` is used to add a new entity to the context, and when you have IDs that are recognized as Identity (auto-generated) this can result in a doubling up since EF will ignore any existing ID on the entity and generate a new one. So if that is an Update only scenario it is better to remove the `Add` all-together and use `Single` rather than `SingleOrDefault` unless it is "ok" that an item might not be found.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use the Add method for new objects. In order to update existing objects, you need to call the Update method.

```
foreach (var item in pricingOptionDTO)
 {
     Entities.PricingOption pricingOptionTb = context.PricingOptions.Where(a => a.ID.Equals(item.ID)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (pricingOptionTb != null)
           {                                                
            pricingOptionTb .DirectPrice = item.DirectPrice;                
            pricingOptionTb .Increment = item.BidIncrement;
            pricingOptionTb .WarningCap = item.BidWarningCap;

            context.Set<PricingOptions>().Update(pricingOptionTb);
           }
         context.SaveChanges(); 
   }
```

You can also set the state of the object to 'Modified'

Comment: `Update` would only be needed if the DbContext is set up to not track changes on the entities. If change tracking is used (on by default) then it's better not to use `Update` or setting the EntityState to Modified so that EF generates UPDATE statements only if values changed, and only for the values that changed. Using `Update` / Modified entity state results in an UPDATE statement for all columns even if nothing had actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it this way:

```
if (pricingOptionTb != null)
{                                                
    pricingOptionTb.DirectPrice = item.DirectPrice;                
    pricingOptionTb.Increment = item.BidIncrement;
    pricingOptionTb.WarningCap = item.BidWarningCap;

    context.Set<Entities.PricingOption>().Attach(pricingOptionTb);
    context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```